# Unable to use struct defined in different header file

Tags: c++, struct, header

I have a project where I need to expand some functionality without touching the project I'm using.

The core of the problem is this (I dumbed it down but the core should be clear).

---

```
//Layout.h
#ifndef LAYOUT_H
#define LAYOUT_H

#include "Speaker.h"

class Layout
{
    public:
        //unrelated stuff
    private:
        LSS::Speaker temp;
};
#endif
```

---

```
//Speaker.h"
#ifndef SPEAKER_H
#define SPEAKER_H
namespace LSS
{
    struct Speaker
    {
        Speaker(int val1, float val2)
        :some_int(val1)
        , some_float(val2)
        {
        }

        ~Speaker()    
        {
            //do other stuff
        }

         int some_int;
         float some_float;

    };//struct Speaker
}
#endif
```

I just want to be able to use the struct Speaker (as defined in "Speaker.h") in "Layout.h" without touching "Speaker.h"

If I compile I get following errors:

> Error 22  error C2512: 'LSS::Speaker' : no appropriate default constructor > available    Layout.cpp  7   1   MyProj

I think that wraps it up - any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty new to c++

Edit: in recreating the issue I made a TYPO (LSS: instead of LSS::). Updated the compiler error

Comment: `LSS:Speaker temp;` that should be `LSS::Speaker temp;` (note the __::__ instead of __:__)

Comment: This is so close to a testcase.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: y u answer in commentz???

Comment: @Lightness, because I thought that might be a typo in the question itself.

Comment: it was indeed a typo in the question :)

Comment: Well [that was the only problem with the posted code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2131f12920023a34), so.... #VTC

Comment: It might help if we could see the line that causes the new error. Presumably, it's a constructor definition, and the constructor is part of the supposedly "unrelated stuff".

Comment: See own answer below. The Speaker class did not have a default constructor specified and I couldn't define one b/c I wasn't allowed to change the Speaker.h/Speaker.cpp so I created a new class which inherited from LSS::Speaker and overloaded it that way

Answer (score 1):

Read carefully message

> Error 3 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'temp' > Layout.h 102 1

and then change `LSS:Speaker temp;` to `LSS::Speaker temp;`

**EDIT:**

For error

> Error 22 error C2512: 'LSS::Speaker' : no appropriate default constructor > available Layout.cpp 7 1 MyProj

if you provide at least one constructor with parameters for Speaker, you also have to provide default constructor (constructor without parameters) to make `LSS::Speaker temp;` valid. It is a rule (for cases when no constructors are written by programmer compiler make default constructor, but if programmer start changing construction logic, compiler do nothing in this part of work).

Or you can provide default values in the existing constructor, like this:

```cpp
  Speaker(int val1 = 0, float val2 = 0.0f)
        :some_int(val1)
        ,some_float(val2)
  {
  }
```

Comment: And how would that error message be helpful? He is not missing a semicolon. Proper solution tho.

Comment: Single colon - is  mistake. Double colon(::) have to be instead

Comment: I know... But the error message you stated tells that he's misssing a semicolon.

Comment: Most valuable in the error message is "syntax error"

Comment: Actually the answer is in comments to question

Comment: @Sambuca: It _is_ helpful, and he _is_ missing a semicolon for as long as that colon is present because that's the only way the code before the colon could be valid. You have to think about the edges a little with compilation errors: the compiler can't read your mind.

Comment: The missing :: was my bad - I misstyped it dumbing down the struct

Comment: So, now the error is in Layout.cpp. Can you provide us with part of code from cpp-file?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the new question, now it's been changed to invalidate previous answers:

> 'LSS::Speaker' : no appropriate default constructor

As the error message says, the class has no default constructor, so it can only be instantiated by providing constructor arguments. You probably want to do this in the `Layout` constructor(s), for example:

```
Layout() : temp(some_value, some_other_value) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to work around Layouts.h not having a default constructor (remember: in this case I wasn't allowed to edit the Speaker() struct)

In Layout.h I defined

```
class Speaker: public LSS::Speaker
{
    public:
        Speaker(): LSS::Speaker(-1, 0.0f){}
};
```

'Overloading' the missing constructor (that I couldn't fill in myself.

Problem solved :)